# How do I Create the Strongest Golden Cookie Combination?

Tags: cookie-clicker

The current process for creating extremely powerful combinations are as follows:

**Golden Cookie Buffs:**
I get a 7x Frenzy. Due to short spawn time, usually on the last 1/4th of the frenzy, another Golden Cookie will spawn. If this one is another CPS boost, such as a building boost or a click power boost, I will activate Force Hand of Fate to try and get the last type of boost not included.

**Pantheon:**
Godzamok in the Diamond slot, Mokalsium in the ruby slot, and Jeremy in the Jade slot. Once I have my three Golden Cookie Buffs online, I sell all for all buildings from Farms to Antimatter Condensers skipping Portals.

**Dragon Aura:**
I have Radiant Appetite and Breath of Milk slotted into the two aura slots.

**Garden:**
I have not set my Garden up to try and synergize with one of these boosts directly. Usually my Garden is set up for full Whiskerbloom when I want to go for max CPS.

This is my current setup for trying to get the highest possible bonus combination which in turn gives me as many cookies as possible within the window. I am wondering however, if there are optimizations to be made?

A few that have I have been thinking about:

**Pantheon:** While Gadzamok and Mokalsium are extremely powerful, I wonder if Muridal would be better than Jeremy (or the other two), as the combination relies heavily on clicks.

**Dragon Aura:**
Radiant Appetite does way too much on its own, so it will be staying, but I wonder if it is worth it to slot Breath of Milk out for something else, such as Dragon Cursor, Reaper of Fields, Dragonflight, or Dragon's Curve.

**Garden:**
What plants should I use to try and make this boosts as strong as possible? I do believe Whiskerbloom is strong, but I wonder if having a full field of mature Thumbcorn in a clay field would be stronger for the purpose of synergizing with the full combination.

The question: What should I do for all aspects of the game that I have control over if I am attempting to create extremely powerful bursts of cookies while utilizing powerful Click Frenzy combinations? What Spirits should I have slotted in my Pantheon for this? What Dragon Auras should I be using? What plants should I have planted in my Garden? What should I set up to try and synergize the most with my Golden Cookie and boost combinations?

Answer (score 1):

For max golden cookie combos, you could fill your garden with golden clovers for maximum golden cookie rates, along with Dragonflight instead of Breath of Milk because x1111 cps per click is insane. For pantheon, perhaps you can replace Jeremy with Vomitrax. That's pretty much all the golden cookie optimization you could do without upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

These strategies come from the official CC Discord, #cookie-clicker channel.

[Earlygame Combo Guide by Lookas](https://pastebin.com/C5QuLWKA) (What you describe in your post is F+CF+BS)

[Advanced Combo Guide by Fillex](https://pastebin.com/dbVyTDCi)

[Endgame Combo Guide by Taru](https://pastebin.com/bMHEJ3R9)